# Error in Wordpress plugin after upgrade to 3.9

Tags: mysql, wordpress, plugins, upgrade, wordpress-3.9

After I've updated my Wordpress install to 3.9, I keep getting these errors:

```
Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/sites/wordpress/site/wp-content/plugins/crm/main.php on line 20

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/sites/wordpress/site/wp-content/plugins/crm/main.php on line 20

Warning: mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/sites/wordpress/site/wp-content/plugins/crm/main.php on line 21
```

I can't quite figure out what's wrong. Here's the code that worked pre-3.9:

```
<?php 
session_start();
/**
 * Plugin Name: CRM
 * Description:  
 * Version:
 * Author: 
 *
 */

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'menu' );

function menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'CRM', 'CRM', 3,'form', 'form' );
}

function form() {
    global $wpdb,$current_user,$user_ID;
    echo "<h3>CRM</h3>";
    $count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user_form_data");
    $nume2 = mysql_fetch_row($count);
    $nume = $nume2[0];
```

I've snipped the rest, as it does not seem relevant for the error :)

**SOLUTION:**

Found it.

The error was in the 3.9 upgrade.

http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/07/mysql-in-wordpress-3-9/

"In WordPress 3.9, we added an extra layer to WPDB, causing it to switch to using the mysqli PHP library, when using PHP 5.5 or higher.

For plugin developers, this means that you absolutely shouldn’t be using PHP’s mysql_*() functions any more – you can use the equivalent WPDB functions instead."

Comment: Did you read those error messages? There is no problem with code, WordPress was unable to connect to database. Check credentials in config.

Comment: Checked the config, and tried to enter mysql with the credentials. 
Nothing wrong there, it seems, as I successfully logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read this post http://make.wordpress.org/core/2014/04/07/mysql-in-wordpress-3-9/

> In WordPress 3.9, we added an extra layer to WPDB, causing it to switch to using the mysqli PHP library, when using PHP 5.5 or higher.
>
> For plugin developers, this means that you absolutely shouldn’t be using PHP’s mysql_*() functions any more – you can use the equivalent WPDB functions instead.

Comment: Indeed! I updated my question with this solution 7 hours ago :)

Answer (score 2):

Change this to wp_results

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user_form_data");
$nume2 = mysql_fetch_row($count);
```

to

```
$count =  $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user_form_data",ARRAY_A);
$nume2 = $wpdb->num_rows; ====== it will return same as mysql_fetch_row
```

Comment: Good example.

This is what I did - replaced ALL the old mysql_* for $wpdb->

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this hope this help



    <?php 
        /**
         * Plugin Name: CRM
         * Description:  any desc
         * Author: ABS
         *
         */

        add_action( 'admin_menu', 'user_data_menu' );

        function user_data_menu() {
                add_menu_page( 'CRM', 'CRM', 3,'user_data_form', 'user_data_form' );
        }

        function user_data_form() {
                @session_start();
                global $wpdb,$current_user,$user_ID;
                echo "<h3>CRM</h3>";
                $count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user_form_data");
                $nume2 = mysql_fetch_row($count);
                $nume = $nume2[0];
                if ( $limit < $nume && empty($_POST['searching']) && empty($_POST['filter_flag']) && empty($_POST['rowsselect']) ) {
                        $start = $_GET['start'];
                        $eu = ($start - 0);
                        $limit = 20;
                        $this4 = $eu + $limit;
                        $back = $eu - $limit;
                        $next = $eu + $limit;   
                }
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but after I tried it out, the error was the same.

Comment: don't use mysql* function they are deprecated. use WP core function or mysqli or pdo. 2nd You're not secure data. sanitize data .

Answer (score -1):

It looks like that the update changed the mysql username and password. So the problem isn't the code.

Check the wp-config.php file if these settings are changed and incorrect

Comment: Nothing is changed inside the wp-config.php file, and the credentials inside it works to access mysql.